# inherit proxy settings through wifi ap

Tags: proxy, wifi, settings

**Setup:**

I have a regular router connected to the internet and which serves as DHCP server for wired connections (it also has WiFi). To that router, I connect connect an Ubuntu 16.04 laptop via cable. In this Ubuntu I configure a proxy system wide (i.e. all internet traffic should go through the defined proxy). The laptop has a WiFi card which should act as an Access Point (AP). The idea is the following: everything that is directly connected to the router (wired or WiFi) should not use the proxy, everything that is connected to the laptop (using its WiFi AP) should automatically use the proxy defined in the laptop's Ubuntu system.

**What works:**

- Proxy configuration on the laptop works well. The external IP of the laptop is that of the proxy, so all is ok.
- I can create a WiFi AP using the creat-ap script found here https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=162895 I can connect other devices to this WiFi AP and the internet pass-through works (i.e. I can browse the internet with the connected devices)

**What does not work:**

- The devices connected to the AP of the laptop are not using the proxy settings. Rather, it would be the same as connecting them directly to the router. So, how can I forward/inherit the proxy settings of the laptop to the devices connected at its AP?

Thanks much in advance for any feedback on this and let me know if you need further information in any direction

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a router on Ubuntu laptop and forcefully forward required traffic received on wireless interface via proxy. Otherwise you will need to configure the clients to use proxy.
[Ubuntu community help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router) page can get you started, but this will require some investment of time.

Comment: Thank you for the hint to the Ubuntu community. I saw that instruction and tried it but I do not see the WiFi (essid UbuntuWireless in the example) with the other devices. Am I missing a step?